# JavaScript: Get Selected Google Marker

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I'm having a google map where google markers are put up. The placement of markers works well. But if I click a marker, the adress should open up in an infowindow. The adress, longtitude and latitude are loaded from model.js into the variable myLocations.

EDIT: Currently a click on any marker returns the adress of the last object in myLocations. But I would like to get the myLocations.adress of the one who was clicked.

```
var markerspots;
var spot;
var j;
for (j = 0; j < myLocations.length; j++){

    spot = {
        lat: parseFloat(myLocations[j].lati),
        lng: parseFloat(myLocations[j].long)
    };

    contentString = myLocations[j].adress;

    markerspots = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: spot,
        map: map,
        icon: markerspot,
        content: contentString,
        id: j
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    google.maps.event.addListener(markerspots, "click", (function(marker) {
        return function(evt) {
            infowindow.setContent(contentString);
            infowindow.open(map, markerspots);
        }
    })(markerspots));
}
```

I have found lots of solutions, but I don't understand any of those. So how can I make the content of the clicked marker show up in an infowindow?

Thanks

Comment: Where do you create `infowindow` and `map`?

Comment: @duncan infowindow is in the lower third, var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(). map can't be found in the piece of code i just posted, but its above that piece and create like this: var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("karte"), kartenoption);

Comment: please post a jsfiddle

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue **in the question itself** (not (just) a jsfiddle)

Comment: duplicate of [Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example), solves your "infowindow issue" with an anonymous function closure.  You need closure on contentString as well as marker.

Comment: @John the project consists of lots of files and folder. I'm not familiar with jsfiddle, but i pasted the html code and the js code. Hope that helps? https://jsfiddle.net/Half_NO_oB/6r678o6t/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are accessing your contentString, which is set to the last one you created in your for loop.
What you really want is the content property of the marker you clicked on, which is stored in **this**.

So

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markerspots, 'click', function() {
   console.log(this.content);
 });
```

should do the trick.

Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/4tpnh00u/

Comment: wow this was on spot! quite the obvious mistake though... "this" fixed the content shown, but not the position. The infowindow always shows up on the position of the last object read from the database. I fixed it with infowindow.open(map, this);